# Angular js don't send custom header while preflight request is made

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have following code

```
angular.module('myApp.Utils',[])
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if (window.localStorage.token) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.token;
            }
            config.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },
        response: function(response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                //redirect user to login page
                $location.url('/login');
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
})
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
});
```

If we have value for `token` key in `localStorage`, it adds `Authorization` Header to every ajax calls made.

**Problem**
It works well if there is no `token` (No header sent). But when token exist in localstorage and I make an API call, I get following error

`Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404`

After research i found that, the browser makes preflight request (OPTIONS request), before making a real request. 
I also found that we cannot send custom Headers in preflight request. So is there anyway to fix this, to send custom Headers only when making a real request.?

I have tried adding following in `.htaccess` of the server that serves API calls

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,HEAD,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found answer myself.

Its not related to angular or .htaccess thing. Its more related to the server side.

When `CORS` request is made, the browser makes a test(preflight) request to see if everything is ok, then only it makes actual request.

Following code in the API call solved the problem.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Authorization');
    exit;
}
```